# Is it possible to create a file that is deleted when its (owning) process goes away?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to create a file on Mac OS X (10.6) that will be deleted automatically when my process goes away. Is this possible? It would be very handy for a file locking scheme I am implementing. Preferably as a Cocoa or Carbon call.

I know that on Windows, this is possible. It's a very neat feature, but I don't know if it is something that needs to be supported by the file system.

On win32 you can call CreateFile with FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE.
In .net you can create a FileStream with FileOptions.DeleteOnClose as argument.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing your own program, you could use tmpfile() call.
It creates a temporary file that get removed automatically on program termination.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a step in the right direction, but this seems to put the file in /tmp/ (right?) and I need to specify where it is located. I realize I didn't state that as a requirement, but it is. :)

Comment: Only problem with that is the temp file is unlinked from the file system as soon as it is created, this means that other processes will not be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your app delegate to create and delete the file via the NSApplicationDelegate, however, the file would remain there if the user force quits/shut down.  If force quitting is not part of your concern, then this should work.  If not, you can create a simple launch agent that checks if your process exists, and if not, delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can register an `atexit()` handler to delete the file, but this will not necessarily be completely reliable, particularly if the program crashes.

If you want proper file locking, consider using [flock()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/flock.2.html), although, it is cooperative.